# Regex to match for repeating numbers in a string

Tags: regex

I have a column like this, I only want to pick rows with repeating numbers

```
Col A
100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100
3,61,3,145,61,61,61,61
299,295,299.5,300,299.5,299
5.98,5.98,397.56,405.51,398.53,7.95,405.51,405.51,398.53
482.14,1522.12,1001.92,1990.39,1000,1999.79
649.36,610.4,1136.75,626.78,590.34
2284.58,1773.35,2169.48,1760.41,1256.36
2979.55,3032.63,3023.23,2505.15
431,154.5,179
302.95,304,304
339.96,159.27,340.74,160.04,153.46,346.54
170,170,170
968.41,8.86,486.5,360.4,102.64
420,500,500
200,250,250
```

regex match for rows that have repeating numbers

1. they can be seperated by non matching numbers as well

Comment: At least show the example of successful match

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a capture group to capture each number, and a back-reference to match a repeat of the number.

```
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b.*\b\1\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/QpwxjT/1)